# How can I change a content value in a value inside of a xml tag attribute using javax.xml.xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Using JAVA and the libraries of javax.xml.xpath, as XpathFactory and XpathExpression,  how can I change the xml tag attribute "6" of the tag "value=6" considering that the XPath is:

```
"number(/suite/test/classes/class/methods/include/parameter[1]/@value)"
```

Do the xPathFactory recognise xpath functions? Or have any other idea?

### Following XML to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Test1" Alowinterrupt="true">
    <test name="testscale">
        <classes>
            <class name="test">
                <methods>
                <include name="poweronoff">
                <parameter name="ScaleTesting" value="6"/>
                </include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify XML File in Java using [DOM parser](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/w/Downloadw3cdomjar.htm).

```
// parse the XML as a W3C Document
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File(xmlFilePath));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/suite/test/classes/class/methods/include/parameter[1]";
Node parameter = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document,
        XPathConstants.NODE);

// update parameter , set the value to 10
NamedNodeMap attribute = parameter.getAttributes();
Node nodeAttr = attribute.getNamedItem("value");

System.out.println("Old id value: " + nodeAttr.getTextContent());
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        .newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFilePath));
nodeAttr.setTextContent("2");
Source input = new DOMSource(document);
transformer.transform(input, output);
System.out.println("New id value: " + nodeAttr.getTextContent());
```

*Output:*

```
Old parameter value: 6
New parameter value: 2
```